How to modify a Python script to extract identifiers from varying path structures in a JSON template
I have a Python script that generates a mapping JSON based off a JSON template.
The script reads the JSON template, then compares a folder structure that has to match the template, so that it can output a new JSON with corresponding values.
This is an example of a line in the JSON template.
"path_structure": "Folder/Apples/{apple_ids}/*",
Then, the script will receive a folder structure like so:
Folder/
└── Apples/
    ├── 43952/
    ├── 53453/
    ├── 12342/
    └── 76552/

The resulting separate JSONs from the script would have the lines:
"value": "43952"
"value": "53453"
"value": "12342"
"value": "76552"
The script looks like this right now.

def get_relative_path(file, start_dir):
  relative_path = os.path.relpath(file, start=start_dir)
  return os.path.normpath(relative_path).split(os.sep)

file_components = get_relative_path(file, start_dir)

def get_path_components(mapping_file_json):
  path_structure = mapping_file_json["path_structure"].rstrip("/*")
  return path_structure.split("/")

path_components = get_path_components(mapping_file_json)

def get_linking_identifier(path_components):
  linking_identifiers = ["{apple_ids}"]

  for linking_identifier in linking_identifiers:
    try:
      linking_identifier_index = path_components.index(linking_identifier)
      return linking_identifier_index
    except ValueError:
      continue

value = file_components[linking_identifier_index]

"value": str(value)


My inquiry is regarding supporting changing the template structure.
I need to support when the JSON template may look like:
"path_structure": "Folder/Apples/notimportant_{apple_ids}/*"
or
"path_structure": "Folder/Apples/{apple_ids}_random/*"
or
"path_structure": "Folder/Apples/random{apple_ids}words/*"
Example folder structures:
Folder/
└── Apples/
    ├── notimportant_43952/
    ├── notimportant_53453/
    ├── notimportant_12342/
    └── notimportant_76552/

or
Folder/
└── Apples/
    ├── 43952_random/
    ├── 53453_random/
    ├── 12342_random/
    └── 76552_random/

And the outputted search values should still look like:
"value": "43952"
"value": "53453"
"value": "12342"
"value": "76552"
How can I best edit my script to support this new functionality?

Edit
Sometimes the search values aren't exclusively numbers. For example, the script can currently support a template and folder structure like:
"path_structure": "Folder/Fruits/{fruit_names}/*"
Folder/
└── Fruits/
    ├── Apples/
    ├── Bananas/
    ├── Mangoes/
    └── Pineapples/

With that, the update would then have to support:
"path_structure": "Folder/Fruits/notimportant_{fruit_names}/*"
Folder/
└── Fruits/
    ├── notimportant_Apples/
    ├── notimportant_Bananas/
    ├── notimportant_Mangoes/
    └── notimportant_Pineapples/

Desired result:
"value": "Apples"
"value": "Bananas"
"value": "Mangoes"
"value": "Pineapples"

Your value is currently 43952_random/ or 43952_random? Similarly, notimportant_43952/ or notimportant_43952?

Can you add all possible combinations of value, as you currently have, and then your expected output? I have to go now... will be back later. This is an easy task, if you provide proper inputs and outputs so that we see.

I need 10 samples of print(str(value))?  You're saying that "the characters in notimportant or random could be anything." That's simply false. It cannot be anything. If we can distinguish it by eyes, which we can in the example you've provided, therefore it can be programmed. But, I need to see samples that covers all your test cases, so that we don't waste time.

I guess you can clean the final value.
Your final value is notimportant_43952/ or 43952_random/. Right?
In that case, you can use clean_value[0]. If you don't have any forward slash, you can simplify your pattern as (?<=_)[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{5}(?=_).
import re
value = """
Folder/
└── Apples/
    ├── notimportant_43952/
    ├── notimportant_53453/
    ├── notimportant_12342/
    └── notimportant_76552/
or

Folder/
└── Apples/
    ├── 43952_random/
    ├── 53453_random/
    ├── 12342_random/
    └── 76552_random/
"""


clean_value = re.findall(r"(?<=_)[0-9]{5}(?=\/)|[0-9]{5}(?=_)", value)
print(clean_value)
# print(clean_value[0])



Prints
['43952', '53453', '12342', '76552', '43952', '53453', '12342', '76552']
43952

Note
If there is no slash in the final value, then we can use:
import re
value = """
Folder/
└── Apples/
    ├── notimportant_43952
    ├── notimportant_53453
    ├── notimportant_12342
    └── notimportant_76552
or

Folder/
└── Apples/
    ├── 43952_random
    ├── 53453_random
    ├── 12342_random
    └── 76552_random
"""


clean_value = re.findall(r"(?<=_)[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{5}(?=_)", value)
print(clean_value)
print(clean_value[0])


Prints
['43952', '53453', '12342', '76552', '43952', '53453', '12342', '76552']
43952


Note

This way you don't really have to touch the code, you can just add another method to clean your "undesired" values.

I don't really know how your "real" data look likes. If you would have posted some samples, it'd have been easier to provide solutions.



Update to the original question - the end result isn't always exclusively digits.

@brained what's in notimportant and random? lowercase alphas? All we need, is to know, which chars are in not important and random and which chars are not and possibly a size?

the characters in notimportant or random could be anything.
example:
loremipsum556_43952
loremipsum556_53453
loremipsum556_12342
Or
43952_randomchar1234
53453_randomchar1234
12342_randomchar1234
The main thing is that the folder structure naming convention is always consistent.
